# Flutter how to migrate this BLoC old version code to Bloc new version

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bloc, migrate

how i must write this code in bloc v.8 i don know how i see some searches but im not understand and this is my code for classes they give me error => StateError (Bad state: add(DoFetchEvent) was called without a registered event handler.
Make sure to register a handler via on((event, emit) {...})):

```
 class PostBloc extends Bloc<PostEvent, PostState> {
           PostRepository repo;

        PostBloc(PostState initialState, this.repo) : super(initialState);

      Stream<PostState> mapEventToState(PostEvent event) async* {
           if (event is DoFetchEvent) {
         yield LoadingState();
       try {
      var posts = await repo.fetchPosts();
       yield FetchSuccess(posts: posts);
     } catch (e) {
    yield ErrorState(message: e.toString());
     }
   }
   }
  }
```

---

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

 class PostEvent extends Equatable {
 @override
 List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class DoFetchEvent extends PostEvent {}
```

---

```
   class PostState extends Equatable {
       @override
        
      List<Object?> get props => [];
     }

     class InitialState extends PostState {}

     class LoadingState extends PostState {}

       class FetchSuccess extends PostState {
             List<PostModel> posts;

            FetchSuccess({required this.posts});
           }

         class ErrorState extends PostState {
         String message;
      ErrorState({required this.message});
             }
```

---

```
   void main() {
 runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: BlocProvider(
  create: (context) => PostBloc(InitialState(), PostRepository()),
     child: MyApp(),
   ),
 ));
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your `InitialState` directly in the `super` constructor without manually passing it in like so.

```
 PostBloc(this.repo) : super(InitialState()) {
    on<DoFetchEvent>(_onDoFetchEvent);
  }
```

Then you no longer pass in any state in the `BlocProvider`

```
 BlocProvider<PostBloc>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => PostBloc(PostRepository()),
...
```

Then your `mapEventToState` gets replaced with a method that takes the relevant `event`, and an `Emitter<PostState>` as arguments. `yield` then gets replaced with `emit` in the method.

Your whole class would look like this.

```
  PostBloc(this.repo) : super(InitialState()) {
    on<DoFetchEvent>(_onDoFetchEvent);
  }

  _onDoFetchEvent(
    DoFetchEvent event,
    Emitter<PostState> emit,
  ) async {
    emit(LoadingState());
    try {
      var posts = await repo.fetchPosts();
      emit(FetchSuccess(posts: posts));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(ErrorState(message: e.toString()));
    }
  }
}
```

That should do it.

Besides that, you're probably getting linter warnings about [must_be_immutable](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=must_be_immutable#must_be_immutable) on your state classes because `PostState` extend `Equatable`.

So I suggest making all `PostState` parameters `final` and adding the `props` override from `Equatable` to your state classes.

```
class ErrorState extends PostState {
  final String message;
  ErrorState({required this.message});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [message];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation, the problem was solved by you, I wish you a nice day

Comment: no problem, happy to help